# Can't get git to read my $HOME/.gitignore file

Tags: git

I've got git version 1.7.9.5 on Ubuntu 12.04.1

I'm trying to set up a global .gitignore file.  I can see git opening my .gitconfig file (6 times!) under strace:

```
$ strace -e trace=open git stat  2>&1 | grep gitconfig
open("/home/roy/.gitconfig", O_RDONLY)  = 3
open("/home/roy/.gitconfig", O_RDONLY)  = 3
open("/home/roy/.gitconfig", O_RDONLY)  = 3
open("/home/roy/.gitconfig", O_RDONLY)  = 3
open("/home/roy/.gitconfig", O_RDONLY)  = 3
open("/home/roy/.gitconfig", O_RDONLY)  = 3
```

and in that file, I've got:

```
[core]
    excludefile = /home/roy/.gitignore
```

but strace says it's not opening the exclude file:

```
$ strace -e trace=open git stat  2>&1 | grep  ignore
open(".gitignore", O_RDONLY)            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open(".~/.gitignore", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What magic am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`excludesfile`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration), not `excludefile`:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = /home/roy/.gitignore
```

Comment: Ah, that would do it.  Thanks!